# Open a form to a specific record from another form Access VBA 2016

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to open a form to a specific record from another form using VBA in Access 2016. I am doing it with the `DoCmd.openForm` but I don't know why it is not working. Is it because of Access 2016 or am I missing something?

Here is my sample code:

```
Docmd.openForm "Add_contacts",,,"frmEntryContacID=" & Me.contac_ID
```

As you can see in the picture, it opens the `Add_Contacts` form but it doesn't display any details information about the contact.

[image]

The `contac_ID` field is where I want to click and open the second form which will give me more details about the contact. So basically the code is going behind the click event of contac_ID. I hope that does not pose a problem.

Help guys please.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is "frmEntryContactID" your field name?  Also is Me.contact_ID a numeric value?

Comment: yes "frmEntryContactID" is my field name on the form I am trying to open, and Me.contact_ID is autoNumber.

Comment: I edited my first post and put the correct names of my fields : "frmEntryContacID" and contac_ID. So the names include contact without the 't'

Comment: Is it `frmEntryContactID` also the name of the field in the record source of the form? I guess not. You should use the fieldname of the record source instead. And: Maybe it's only a typo? `contac_ID` looks like a `t` is missing.

Comment: Your code should be: DoCmd.OpenForm "Add_contacts", , , "Contac_ID=" & Me.Contac_ID  

Change the "frmEntryContacID=" to "Contac_ID="

It works fine on my end

Comment: Sorry it’s not working, I did as you have suggested. Can you please post a screen shot of yours?

Comment: The only time it works on my end is when I leave the ‘Add_Contacts’ form open then click the id field on the  ‘Contacs_List’ form,  it will take me back to the open ‘Add_Contacts’ form  displaying the right information. But that’s not how I want it to work. I want to make it work as intended

Comment: You said it worked fine on your end, are you working with  access 2016? Because I really don’t why it’s not working on my end.  Your help is appreciated

Comment: Hi, I have an example here http://vbahowto.com/how-to-open-a-form-to-a-specific-record-in-access-2016-vba/

Comment: Some bozo the clown likely set the forms data Entry setting = "yes". That means the form ONLY shows new records and allows ONLY new records to be displayed. Change the data entry = No will fix this.

Comment: DataEntry=True (Ah hah)... Good find!

Comment: @Albert D Kallal you were right changing the data entry setting made the difference. You are a big clown for clowning me hahaha

Comment: Thanks @Erik Loebl none of this would have been possible without your relentless replies. Thank you and I’ll watch your video right now for more insights

Comment: Will conditional statements help me get around changing my data entry setting to ‘no’?  Because I want my ‘Add_Contacts’ form always ready for new entry.

Comment: Just, go to a new record after you open the form.  DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Nice one, as always you rock!

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to open a form  with specific record using `Docmd.OpenForm`

**1.** `DoCmd.OpenForm "Add_contacts", , , "Contac_ID=" & Me.Contac_ID` which @Erik has already mentioned. 
     Make sure **`Add_contacts`** form is bound to `Contacs` table and **`Allow Filters`** property is set to Yes.

**2.** Use the **`OpenArgs`** property to pass the parameter value to new form. 
     `DoCmd.OpenForm "Add_contacts", , ,, , , Me.Contac_ID`

And add below code to `Add_Contacts` form

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    If Not IsNull(Me.OpenArgs) Then
         Me.RecordSource = "select * from Contacs Where Contac_ID=" & Me.OpenArgs
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried both options, and none of them worked. I am starting to wonder if the problem is not Access 2016, have you tried these option on Access 2016?  I really don't know what to say at this point. if you are interested you can take a look at my code through team viewer.

Comment: @Douk Are you getting any error? This code should work for 2016

Comment: No I am not getting any error, it just opens the form to a new record. refer to the above  screen shot

Comment: Can you please try it on access 2016? Since you are more experienced in Access VBA than me , if you encounter the problem it will be easier for you to figure it out than me. This thing is making me go nuts. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: I know it's probably too late but I was having this very same problem. In your code `Docmd.openForm "Add_contacts",,,"frmEntryContacID=" & Me.contac_ID` frmEntryContacID should be changed to the actual name of the field in the Contacts table NOT the form field name.